# Update panel prevents jquery from working?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, webforms

I have this script on a page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var btnApplyVoucher = document.getElementById('LbtnApplyVoucher');
            var voucher = document.getElementById('TxtVoucher');
            $("input.voucherCode").bind('keyup paste', function () {
                btnApplyVoucher.setAttribute("class", "displayBlack");
            });
            $("input.voucherCode").bind('blur', function () {
                if (voucher.value == '') {
                    btnApplyVoucher.removeAttribute("class", "displayBlack");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

and I have this textbox which is being manipulated by the above jquery

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdBasket" runat="server">
...
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtVoucher" Text="" runat="server" CssClass="voucherCode" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
...
<asp:LinkButton ID="LbtnUpdateBasket" runat="server" Text="Update Basket" OnClick="LbtnUpdateBasket_Click"/></div>
...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My problem is when LbtnUpdateBasket is clicked and the update panel updates my jquery stops functioning?! I am not sure what I can do here and nothing I can find on the web is really that helpful to me? I believe my problem is something to do with the `.ready()` which is running when the page loads but ofcourse this wont run on the update as the whole page doest load, what can i do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also fire the jQuery when the update panel updates, as well as when the page loads.

For Example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Get page request manager
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        //Add handler for end request (update panel, end update)
        prm.add_endRequest(configurePage);

        $(document).ready(configurePage);

        function configurePage() {
            var btnApplyVoucher = document.getElementById('LbtnApplyVoucher');
            var voucher = document.getElementById('TxtVoucher');
            $("input.voucherCode").bind('keyup paste', function () {
                btnApplyVoucher.setAttribute("class", "displayBlack");
            });
            $("input.voucherCode").bind('blur', function () {
                if (voucher.value == '') {
                    btnApplyVoucher.removeAttribute("class", "displayBlack");
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click a button the AJAX request is sent, and then the entire HTML content of the `UpdatePanel` is re-created based on the results of that request.  All of the changes that your JQuery code made will then need to be re-applied.  You'll need to ensure that the appropriate code to re-apply those JQuery bindings is run within whatever your link button's click handler is fired.